# NIntegrate vs. summation

Tags: numerical-integration

I' m interesting in distributions of points on sphere, plane figures etc.
Especially for small number of points: 1, 3, 7, ...

It seems that good criterion for uniformity of distribution is some generalization of
mass center criterion.

Let's think about unit disk and N "seeds" on it.
For every point of disk {x,y} let's find closest seed and the Euclidean length squared to it.
Average this over all the points {x,y} and try to minimize it.
For N=1 we will get exactly mass center. For N>1 we will get some interesting
 "the most even" configurations.

With Mathematica we have:

```
myDist[point_, seeds_] :=SquaredEuclideanDistance[point, Nearest[seeds, point][[1]]] 
/;VectorQ[point, NumericQ] && MatrixQ[seeds, NumericQ]; 

optValue[seeds_]:=(1/Pi) NIntegrate[
        myDist[{x, y}, seeds] Boole[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 1], 
      {x, -diam, diam}, {y, -diam, diam}]/; MatrixQ[seeds, NumericQ];
```

This integration have to be very fast since it should be optimized later with `NMinimize[]`. 
I've tried many methods; the best result for `Length[seeds]=5`  is **0.36 second** with:

```
Method -> {"MultiDimensionalRule","Generators" -> 5}, MaxRecursion -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 4
```

But using "brutal force" summation over net of points:

```
step = 0.07;
net = Reap[Do[
        Do[
          If[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 1, Sow[{x, y}]], 
        {x, -1, 1, step}],
       {y, -1, 1, step}]][[2, 1]];
optVal = Total[symbDist[#, seeds]& /@ net]/Length[net];
```

we can get the same `PrecisionGoal = 4` **within 0.016 second!** (the same computer)
I understand that integrable function `myDist` is weird enough.
By maybe someone help me to find good and fast integration method for it?

Comment: Id suggest you provide a real example. " plane figures etc. " suggests more complicated situations that might lead to different approaches than your circle.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-calculating the Nearest function, performing the integral in polar coordinates and relaxing the patterns will give you a nice speedup (60%/80% in my experiments):

```
SeedRandom[42];
seeds = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];
diam = 1;
memF = Nearest[seeds];
myDist[point_] := #.# &@(point - First@memF[point]) /; VectorQ[point, NumericQ]
optValue[seeds_] := (1/Pi) NIntegrate[myDist[r {Cos@phi, Sin@phi}] r, 
                                             {r, 0, diam}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 4]
optValue[seeds] // Timing
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you!
For optimization purposes I edit your code like this:
 `myDist[point_, seeds_] := 
  With[{memF = Nearest[seeds]}, #.# &@(point - First@memF[point])] /; 
   VectorQ[point, NumericQ] && MatrixQ[seeds, NumericQ];`

Comment: Sorry, your advice is good, but not exact answer on my question. With `NIntegrate[]` and new `myDist` I get ~0.15 sec. It's really better.
But with direct summation `directOpt[pnts_, step_, diam_] := Module[{s = 0, j = 0},
    Do[Do[
      If[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 1, 
         (j = j + 1; s = s + myDist[{x, y}, pnts])],
      {x, -diam, diam, step}], {y, -diam, diam, step}];
    s/j] /; MatrixQ[pnts, NumericQ];`
I get ~0.01 sec.
NIntegrate[] fail anyway...

Comment: @lesobrod You're comparing pears with apples.